# Working with CheckedListBox MultiColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm using a `checkedlistbox` with just `one column`. But now, I need a field to `validate` the checked item. I used the `MultColumn = True` of the `Checkedlistbox` but I couldn't.

What I need is to have a list of items to the user select, then another field on the side to say if its a `Required` field. e.g

`[ ]Name    [ ]Required`
`[ ]birthday    [ ]Required`

I need a way (may be using other tool than `checkedlistbox`) to say if that field `Required` or not...

Answer (score 0):

I would think of using your own UserControl for this. You could easily create custom control with two checkedlistbox.

I'd have a `ValidatedCheckedListboxControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` with two checkedListbox inside. You can add a public method to add to your fields lists (say fieldsCheckedList) so you can also add another to your 'has to be' list.

Also another method `hasToBe(int element){ return hasToBeList[element].Checked);}`

Comment: Could you be more specific please, I didnt get it well ;s
Just create two checkedlistbox ? How would I compare if the field 1 `hastobe`or not ? Maybe with index ? Could you help me on this please... Its for my work ;\